# In Eclipse how to copy all linked resources to project folder?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have imported some Eclipse C++ project. But in that project there are some **linked resources**. I want them to be in the project folder. Is there a way to make that from Eclipse?

Comment: Do you mean in your workspace?

Comment: Deleting the resource from the Project Explorer (which will not delete the target folder), and then moving or copying the target folder into the project folder, should work.